# Besse's Einstein manifolds typo: Euler characteristics of complex projective space is $m$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, projective-space

In

*Besse, Arthur L.*, [Einstein manifolds](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540741206), Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete. 3. Folge, Bd. 10. Berlin etc.: Springer-Verlag. XII, 510 p. DM 198.00 (1987). [ZBL0613.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0613.53001).

On page 161 there is a suspicious equality $\chi(\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^m)=m$. There is nothing in the errata list on last page of the book. Is there something here that I missed it or it is a typo and it should be $\chi(\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^m)=m+1$?

Comment: There are notions of a reduced Euler characteristic that is just the usual minus one, but if he does not mention this I would suspect it is just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typo. All other formulas on the page that follow are for the unreduced Euler characteristic where $\chi(\Bbb{CP}^m) = m+1$.